# Android Auto App Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-auto

I have created android auto app, the issue is I am able to test it on Emulator but when I try it to test it on Head Unit my app is not listed.
I have gone through different reference [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/auto.html) , [here](https://developer.android.com/design/auto/index.html#overview-screen) and come to conclusion that I have to upload my app on play store for alpha and beta testing and then it is available on Head unit (HMI) but it will slow my testing and development process.

Is there any another way?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you can do it. You just need to make it look as though the app has come from the Play Store (don't do this for anything other than testing purposes).

Create an apk for the app, then go to that folder and push it to the phone. Next, install it with the right signature (com.android.vending), then remove the apk from the phone once installed.

Something like this will work:

```
adb push mobile-debug.apk /sdcard/app.apk
adb shell pm install -i "com.android.vending" -r /sdcard/app.apk
adb shell rm /sdcard/app.apk
```

Best of luck!